# Why am i getting this if else error in ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, syntax-error

```
shit_loot = ['Worn Dagger', 'Dirty Panties', 'Broken Staff', 'Bear Claw', 'Used Bandage']
decent_loot = ['Simple Staff', 'Alchemy Bag', 'Mask of Emptiness', 'Cloak of Disappearance', 'Large Health Potion']
epic_loot = ['Sword of 1000 Truths', 'The Master Sword', 'BFG', 'The Fate of the World', 'Infinite Bag of Infinity']

puts "On a scale of 1 - 10 how hard was the battle for the party?"
cr = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Your party completed a challenge rating #{cr} battle, Great Work!"

if cr <= 3 
  puts "Your loot is #{shit_loot.sample}, #{shit_loot.sample}, #{shit_loot.sample}. Grats on the shitty loot!"

  elsif cr >= 4 && <= 8
    puts "Your loot is #{decent_loot.sample}, #{decent_loot.sample}, #{decent_loot.sample}. Grats on the decent loot!"

  else cr > 8
    puts "Your loot is #{epic_loot.sample}, #{epic_loot.sample}, #{epic_loot.sample}. Grats on the epic loot!"
end
```

ruby battle_loot_calc.rb
battle_loot_calc.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected <=
  elsif cr >= 4 && <= 8

Answer (score 1):

Add `cr` following `&&` like so:

`elsif cr >= 4 && cr <= 8 puts`...

Answer (score 1):

You could use case with ranges :

```
adjective = case cr
when (0..3) then 'shit'
when (4..8) then 'decent'
when (9..10) then 'epic'
end
```

So your code becomes :

```
possible_loots = {
  'shitty' => ['Worn Dagger', 'Dirty Panties', 'Broken Staff', 'Bear Claw', 'Used Bandage'],
  'decent' => ['Simple Staff', 'Alchemy Bag', 'Mask of Emptiness', 'Cloak of Disappearance', 'Large Health Potion'],
  'epic' => ['Sword of 1000 Truths', 'The Master Sword', 'BFG', 'The Fate of the World', 'Infinite Bag of Infinity']
} 

adjective = case cr
when (0..3) then 'shitty'
when (4..8) then 'decent'
when (9..10) then 'epic'
end

loot = (1..3).map{ possible_loots[adjective].sample}.join(', ')
puts "Your loot is #{loot}. Grats on the #{adjective} loot!"

# cr = 5
#=> Your loot is Cloak of Disappearance, Simple Staff, Alchemy Bag. Grats on the decent loot!
# cr = 10
#=> Your loot is Infinite Bag of Infinity, BFG, The Master Sword. Grats on the epic loot!
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick responses and the helpful information!